# How to get the text of a css class using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

In a webpage I am scraping, there is the CSS code:

```
<span class="err css-bjzkj7">OUT OF STOCK</span>
```

I want to get the text "OUT OF STOCK" and check to see if it's changed.

What I tried:

```
from splinter import Browser
driver = Browser('chrome', **executable_path)
driver.visit(url)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("err css-bjzkj7").text
```

What I get:

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'
```

I read about "xpath" but that throws the same error.
Selenium version: 3.141.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `find_by_css()` when you use `splinter`

```
driver.find_by_css(".err.css-bjzkj7").text
```

Or

```
 driver.find_by_css(".err").text
```

Splinter official doc says. you can refer this.
[Find Element](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/finding.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how did you try `xpath` but my suggestion would be:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'err css-bjzkj7')]").text
```